# Windows XP doesn't start up dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have installed windows XP first and then Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have 2 or 3 times upgraded Ubuntu with newer versions. Both were working fine. No problem

A few weeks ago I upgraded Ubuntu again and I believe after the upgrade I can't start windows XP via GRUB. The option "Start Windows XP" is in the GRUB overview and now when I select Windows XP at the grub screen, it goes black and stays black. "It hangs".
Windows is still there because I have tried with the Windows XP install disc and choose the 'R'epair choice. then I get the question which windows version do you want to connect to or somenthing like that. Then you have to fill the admin password.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I have tried several things:

1. How to fully fix the Windows bootloader using a Windows disk [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader) was I think not a good choice because the complete didn't came anymore. So I could not start windows and Ubuntu anymore
2. Installed Ubuntu newer version 13.xx again, I hope that then GRUB
   would recover
3. Boot-repair:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
4. I have tried boot-repair by terminal mode. I get the result that is was succeeded
5. Maybe some more things but I can't recover all my trials.

****************** *EDIT* ********************

I'm a little bit further. I have done again step 1, exept fixmbr.
If I choose now windows then I get the boot.ini startup menu what is written in the.

I have added the safe mode to the boot.ini. When I choose this then it hangs with loading bootvld.dll (I believe that was the name. I can't check it at the moment.). If check the normal startup then the screen is turned into black and the computer "hangs".

I have copied the two files ntldr and ntdetect.com from the i386 dir. to the root. I have done this with ubuntu.

What I was asking myself is, boot.ini:
        [default]

```
    multi(0).... partition(1)="Windows XP" 

    [....]

    multi(0).... partition(1)="Windows XP" /fastdetect

    multi(0).... partition(1)="Windows XP safe mode" with some switches
```

Is this right? **How do I know that Windows is on partition 1?** is there a tool?
And I've been searching for a example of a boot.ini file with dual boot.

Comment: Add links in the comment and I'll add them for you, these rules about reputation is to limit spam on the site, not to limit the users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/10698)